# setkey and the := operator, data.table, R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, apply

When using the `data.table` package, I am a bit unsure of when i need to `setkey()`. For example, when using the `:=` operator with the `by` option, things seem to still be very fast even though I have not set a key. Could someone please elucidate when `setkey()` is necessary and when it is not? And if it is not necessary prior to calling `:=` with `by` then how is the `data.table` package so fast since presumably it has to do the same thing as `apply` in standard `data.frame` R by doing a sequential search rather than a binary one since it doesn't know whether my `data.table` is actually sorted by the argument to `by`.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These 2 FAQs seem close :

> *3.2 I don't have a key on a large table, but grouping is still really quick. Why is that?*
> `data.table` uses radix sorting. This is signicantly faster than other sort algorithms. Radix is specifically for integers only, see `?base::sort.list(x,method="radix")`. This is also one reason why `setkey` is quick. When no key is set, or we group in a different order from that of the key, we call it an ad hoc by.
>
> *3.3 Why is grouping by columns in the key faster than an ad hoc by?*
> Because each group is contiguous in RAM, thereby minimising page fetches, and memory can be copied in bulk (`memcpy` in C) rather than looping in C.

What it doesn't say, and probably should do, is that you need a very large dataset, where each group is also very large, before you notice the difference between keyed by and ad hoc by. Something like 100 groups of 100MB each (a 10GB data.table) such as 1e8 rows and 13 columns. Otherwise, there is no need to `setkey` first, especially since that can get onerous.

Comment: fantastic, thank you! was digging through the FAQ and must have missed this.

Comment: Does `ad hoc by` is fast because it uses radix sorting as well?

Comment: @colinfang Difficult to answer that question since several features come into it. The reasons vary according to query and data. Ad hoc `by` does use radix sorting to find the groups for integer columns, so it depends on type and how many columns are being 'by'-ed. Then once it has found the groups, one reason grouping is fast is because memory is allocated for the largest group once up front which is then reused for all groups. And only for the columns needed by `j`. See FAQ 3.1. Try `verbose=TRUE` mode as it reveals how much time is spent finding the groups (inc radix sort) vs iterating them.